# Alter default membership provider model definition

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, membership-provider

We are using the **System.Web.Security.DefaultMembershipProvider** on our project and we’ve hit a wall.

This particular implementation of the MembershipProvider contract uses a hard coded model definition (**System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.membershipSsdl and Sytem.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.membershipCsdl**) to create the model and resulting database using EntityFramework.

This particular model definition sets the max length of the **UserName** field to **50** characters and the max length of the **Email** field to **256** characters. Now in a lot of scenarios our users may want to/be required to user their email address as their username. Clearly this won’t be possible for a lot of them as the data validation within this model will fail.

From what I can see there is no way to override this model definition, and the source code to the ASPNET Universal Providers library is not available on CodePlex as part of the Microsoft Open Source program. However, resharper in visual studio will perform a good amount of decompilation that allows us to see the inner workings of the implementation.

At this juncture we are resigned to going down the ‘implement your own membership provider’ route, but I/we wanted to see if anyone out there had any advice/alternative thoughts/suggestions around this problem. Otherwise it looks like we are going to duplicate several thousand lines of existing MS code just to change a couple of characters.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is interested in this issue, we decided against rolling our own provider datastore and simply hid the usage of the username field away from the end user. Their email address was used as their 'username' but internally we actually stored a guid in the username field and wrote some code to internally translate from email to 'username' before performing things like authentication. Not great, but it got us over the line.